# How can I launch the GNOME image viewer from the terminal?

Tags: ubuntu, gnome

It's the default image viewer for Ubuntu, and apparently it's called Eye of Gnome. I would like to be able to launch it from the command line, passing it a file name to open.

Comment: Thanks for asking and answering this question! I always forget the name of this program.

Comment: `eog` is so barebones it can't display animated GIFs. I use XnViewMP, which on the other hand is a bit slower.

Comment: @DanDascalescu, I just tried it on ubuntu, and it worked fine on an animated GIF I created

Answer (score 219, accepted):

The command to use is [`eog`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/natty/man1/eog.1.html) (**E**ye **o**f **G**NOME). And you call it like so:

```
eog filename
```

Comment: I came here looking for eye of mate, which is the command `eom filename` hope that helps anyone else

Comment: To open full screen `eog -f filename`

Answer (score 40):

Use [`xdg-open`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/xdg-open):

```
xdg-open filename
```

which opens a file or URL in the user's preferred application.

---

### Explanation

As long as you use [Gnome](https://www.gnome.org/) and [`eog`](https://help.gnome.org/users/eog/stable/commandline.html.en) is your [default image viewer](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Default_applications#gnome-defaults-list), you can use [`gnome-open`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/man1/gnome-open.1.html):

```
gnome-open filename
```

If you want an alternative that is independent of the desktop environment, use [`xdg-open`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/xdg-open) which is bash [wrapper](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/144047/how-does-xdg-open-do-its-work) around environment-specific commands.

For now, [`xdg-open`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/xdg-open) supports:

1. [Xfce](http://www.xfce.org/) ([`exo-open "$1"`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/exo-open)),
2. [Gnome](https://www.gnome.org/) ([`gvfs-open "$1"`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/man1/gvfs-open.1.html), [`gnome-open "$1"`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/man1/gnome-open.1.html) with [fallback](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25377545/what-it-is-a-fallback-html5) to generic open),
3. [KDE](https://www.kde.org/) ([`kde-open "$1"`](https://superuser.com/questions/292999/kde-equivalent-of-gnome-open-file-command) with fallback to [`kfmclient exec "$1"`](https://techbase.kde.org/Development/Tools/Using_kfmclient)),
4. [Mate](http://mate-desktop.com/) ([`gvfs-open "$1"`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/man1/gvfs-open.1.html), `mate-open $1`),
5. [LXDE](http://lxde.org/) ([`pcmanfm $1`](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/PCManFM) with fallback to generic open),
6. [Enlightenment](https://www.enlightenment.org/) (`enlightenment_open $1`),
7. [Cinnamon](https://cinnamon-spices.linuxmint.com/) (`open_gnome3 $1`, which is [`gvfs-open "$1"`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/man1/gvfs-open.1.html) with fallback to generic open),
8. [Cygwin](https://www.cygwin.com/) ([`cygstart "$1"`](https://gist.github.com/charlesroper/317713)),
9. [Darwin](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Darwin_(operating_system)) (`open "$1"`).

and tries its luck with other desktop environments (called *generics*). [`$1`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5163260/1321680) is your image filename.

---

### Usage

```
xdg-open filename
```

If you want to figure out how [`xdg-open`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/xdg-open) works, you can read [bash](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bash_(Unix_shell)) source code:

```
$ locate xdg-open
/usr/bin/xdg-open
/usr/share/man/man1/xdg-open.1.gz
$ less /usr/bin/xdg-open
```

---

### Edit

See also [similar answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/144048/28115) for different question on [unix.stackexchange.com](https://unix.stackexchange.com/).

Answer (score 2):

For Fedora you can use `shotwell filename`.

Answer (score 0):

I opened cat.jpg. Then I typed

```
ps x | grep cat.jpg
```

eog was being used to open my file