# Kde equivalent of `gnome-open file` command

Tags: command-line, gnome, kde

There is cool CLI utility an `gnome-open file` which does an application launch given the file the same way as douburu-clicking on this file in file-manager of gnome.

How should I do the same with kde? (launch the same application as it will be done as doubre clicking it in konquerorer?)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

KDE's version of that command is `kde-open`.

However, there's also a universal version that should work in any desktop environment called `xdg-open`.  Get in the habit of using that and you won't need to figure out a new command if you decide to switch to something else besides KDE later.

Comment: when the kde-open and xdg-open was added? (which version of ubuntu and"or version of kde"gnome)

Comment: `xdg-open` seems to have been in Ubuntu as early as 8.04 Hardy Heron.  It's part of the `xdg-utils` package which is usually installed by default.  `kde-open` has been in KDE since KDE 3, before Ubuntu even existed.

Comment: To learn more about `xdg-open` see [this answer](http://superuser.com/a/918994/139893) for [related question](http://superuser.com/q/104599/139893).

Answer (score 2):

Also, `kfmclient exec` seems to do the thing.