# How can I launch Eye of MATE Image Viewer from the command line?

Tags: linux, mate

In Linux, How can I launch MATE's Eye of MATE Image Viewer from the command line?

Searching found:

- [How can I launch the GNOME image viewer from the terminal?](https://superuser.com/questions/104599/how-can-i-launch-the-gnome-image-viewer-from-the-terminal)
- https://mate-desktop.org/
- https://learnubuntumate.weebly.com/image-viewer.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The name of binaries can be different depending on the distribution. On Arch it is `eom`.

Generally, when you have a desktop icon or similar, this is defined in a file in `/usr/share/applications`. When you identified the file you can look at the line that contains `Exec=` to see what command is executed to start the respective program.